# Как правильно вывести текст на экран в android?

Tags: java, android

Учусь разрабатывать приложения на Java. Скажем так, моё приложение должно выводить число на экран. Для этого на экране был создан объект, в коде ему присваивалось значение переменной. По началу я не лез никуда, кроме `GameActivity.java`(код для `acrivity_game.xml`, которое я создал), и данные действия там проделывались следующим образом:

```
TextView textObjectPartA;
TextView textObjectPartB;

TextView textObjectPartA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
TextView textObjectPartB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartB);

int partA = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
partA++;
int partB = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
partB++;

textObjectPartA.setText(""+partA);
textObjectPartB.setText(""+partB);
```

При запуске приложения и открытия, отладчик выдавал такую ошибку

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Я смотрел обсуждение проблемы вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113625/do-not-concatenate-text-displayed-with-settext-use-resource-string-with-placeho), и делал, как указано в ответе:

Файл strings.xml

```
<string name="part_a">part a value = %1$d.</string>
<string name="part_b">part b value = %1$d.</string>
```

Файл activity_game.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPartB"
        android:text="@string/part_b"
...
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPartA"
        android:text="@string/part_a"
```

GameActivity.java

```
 Resources res = getResources();
        String partA_text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.part_a), partA);
        textObjectPartA.setText(partA_text);
        String partB_text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.part_b), partB);
        textObjectPartB.setText(partB_text);
```

Также я пробовал простое решение - просто написать

```
textObjectPartA.setText(String.valueOf(partA));
textObjectPartB.setText(String.valueOf(partB));
```

Данная ошибка не исчезает. Программа также вылетает при попытке загрузить это Activity. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: опишите пожалуйста что именно вы здесь делаете - `randInt.nextInt(numberRange)`, я допускаю что ошибка указывает на эту строку. В логах там где вы брали текст ошибки, можно увидеть ссылку на строку где возникла проблема

Comment: здесь рандомное число генерируется, ошибка указывает на строку textObjectPartA.setText(""+partA);

Comment: могу скинуть ссылку на репозиторий на гитхабе, но вряд ли кому-то захочется туда смотреть)

Comment: а numberRange вы откуда берете?

Comment: int numberRange = currentLevel * 3;

Comment: вероятнее всего проблема в генерации числа, вы просто текст пробовали засетить?

Comment: там долгая система, я много гуглил, и ошибка точно не в использовании класса random https://github.com/SeBorgey/FirstGame если интересно

Comment: textObjectPartA.setText(""+2); только что так написал, ошибка осталась

Comment: добавил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После ознакомления с репой ТС стало понятно в чем проблема. Попробуйте использовать такой пример присваивания значение виджету :

```
public TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    
}
```

Вы объявили один глобальный виджет в классе, а присвоили значение локальному. То есть у вас программа не понимает что это за виджеты:

```
TextView textObjectPartA;
TextView textObjectPartB;
```

в onCreate() уберите слово TextView:

```
textObjectPartA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
textObjectPartB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartB);
```

и присвойте значение виджетам так как вы это сделали здесь:

```
textObjectScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textScore);
textObjectLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLevel);
```

и дальше вы сможете работать с глобальными виджетами из любого места в классе. И вероятнее всего ошибка исчезнет :)

Comment: пока не всё понял из ответа, но понял главное - я переопределил в методе эти объекты. Я знаю, что это делает их локальными, но тупо не заметил этого, во дурень.:D И даже не обратил внимание, что эти методы у меня серого цвета - то есть они не используются. Пока просто написал textObjectPartA.setText(String.valueOf(partA)); и всё заработало. Сейчас буду дальше ответ осмыслять. Спасибо!